# Google App Engine application deployment fails despite readiness_check returning a 200 status response

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to setup a `readiness_check` for my application. Here's the related section of my `app.yaml`:

```
readiness_check:
  path: '/readiness_check'
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 10
  success_threshold: 1
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
```

([Full config](https://gist.github.com/mvlabat/5a497471d4aa7faec7e091d2ecd11f98))

The project I'm developing is a Node.js application working on Express. Here's how I handle the `/readiness_check` endpoint:

```
app
  .get(['/readiness_check'], (req, res) => res.sendStatus(200))
```

Without `readiness_check` configured, my deployment process succeeds and I can access my application without any problems. However, when I include the `readiness_check`, the process fails with the following error:

> OperationError: Error Response: [4] Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.

I checked the logs and I could see that `/readiness_check` returned `502` at first (while the application was still starting) and then started to return `200` status codes. Accessing the endpoint with `curl` manually showed the same results. But still for some reason GCP didn't see my deployment as healthy.

Running `gcloud app describe` confirms that I have `splitHealthChecks` feature enabled.

I walked through [troubleshooting sections in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-aeflex-deployment) and discovered that I didn't have `servicecontrol.googleapis.com` and `endpoints.googleapis.com` services enabled, so I enabled them, but that didn't help either.

I also saw the following note in the documentation:

> If you examine the nginx.health_check logs for your application, you might see health check polling happening more frequently than you have configured, due to the redundant health checkers that are also following your settings. These redundant health checkers are created automatically and you cannot configure them.

It might be an unrelated question, but I couldn't find `nginx.health_check` in my application logs. I tried to search for "nginx" text, but I didn't see anything related to health checking. Though when looking for "readiness_check" it indeed showed me the responses that I've mentioned above.

Comment: Can you show us your full `app.yaml` file to get more context?

Comment: @LundinCast sure! Here you go: https://gist.github.com/mvlabat/5a497471d4aa7faec7e091d2ecd11f98
Also added the link to the main post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be more possible ways to fix this:

1) You can increase the values in the `resources` rubric within your `app.yaml` file. You can check more about this [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings).

2) You can increase the value of `app_start_timeout_sec` to [the maximum value](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#readiness_path), which is 1800. That way you can give a bit more time to your app to become healthy.

3) Even though, running `gcloud app describe` confirms that you have splitHealthChecks feature enabled, did you do the all the proper steps in migrating the health check from the legacy version? Is it applied to all the versions of your app, even the old ones?
You can check carefully all the steps that needed to be taken to convert the health checks [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating-to-split-health-checks#converting_legacy_health_check_options). Applying the command `gcloud app update --split-health-checks --project [YOUR_PROJECT_ID]` may not be enough.

**EDIT:**
Even though, theoretically, if you did not [split your traffic across different versions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/splitting-traffic), this should not be a problem ( I cannot think for a reason why it would be ). In the documentation about migration, in the step 2, it says that :

> Convert legacy health check options for each version in your application.

In order to do that, you should write and update the `app.yaml` accordingly for each version and, then deploy the service, as [assigned to a certain version ID](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app#deploying_a_service_3). eg : `gcloud app deploy --project PROJECT_ID --version VERSION_ID --no-promote`

4) As a workaround, you could "fake" the `readiness_check` response, to give a 200 status response after a certain time. You would have to add a custom handler in [this section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/reference/app-yaml#readiness_path). This way the deployment won't time out, and will keep working in the background. However, this misses the purpose of the readiness checks, as your instance might receive traffic when it's not ready to do so. If you have this in mind, and can handle this in your application, it would be an option to consider.

Finally, I suppose you are using App Engine Flex, as for the Standard version the healthchecks are not available and there will be errors. You can check [this discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/IWNzceG4FxY).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems to me that 1 and 2 is not a problem in my case, because the application did work with such amount of resources before and I'm able to access my application and confirm the working endpoint manually before the check times out.

But I can't say the same about the third point.. How do I make sure that the feature is applied to the older versions of my app as well? I'm introducing the new health check config only in the newest version I'm trying to deploy, obviously.. Does that mean that the older versions still use the legacy health check?

Comment: I have edited my answer with more details about why I think so and how to do that.  I still think that increasing app_start_timeout_sec: 1800 would be worth trying. If you said your app is initially failing and then everything is ok, you will just give the health check "more time to think".

Comment: You were right, increasing app_start_timeout_sec did help. I was afraid of increasing the timeout, thinking that gcloud won't perform any checks until the specified time passes, but it appears I misinterpreted that. Still it's strange that gcould couldn't access my application's readiness_check endpoint, but I could (and I'm sure that was at least a minute before it decided to abort the deploy process). Maybe I was able to access just one of the instances, but not all of them were actually ready. Thank you again!

Comment: Yeah... Debug mode tells me that starting all the instances of my application takes around 14mins, so my assumption that 5min would be enough was completely wrong :D